# Error setting text for option in jquery loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I have the following code:

```
 $('#selectid option').each(function(){
        if( this.text.indexOf("abcxyz") >= 0){
            var lable = this.text.replace("abcxyz", "");
            this.text(lable);
        }
    });
```

I do not understand why I get this error:

> this.text is not a function

What's my code wrong? Please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks all.

Comment: use this `$(this).text()`

Comment: try this $(this).text(lable);

Comment: I did your way and succeeded, Thanks all:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `$(this)` instead of `this`:

```
$('#selectid option').each(function(){
    if( $(this).text().indexOf("abcxyz") >= 0){
        var lable = $(this).text().replace("abcxyz", "");
        $(this).text(lable);
    }
});
```

Comment: You've also changed `.text` into `.text()`

Answer (score 1):

```
    $('#selectid option').each(function(){            
        if( this.text.indexOf("abcxyz") >= 0){          
        var lable = this.text.replace("abcxyz", "");
        this.text=lable;
       }
    });
```